# How to make a %var% worth multiple lines of echos? - Batch

Tags: batch-file

Say I have a variable called %Inventory%
and

```
echo %inventory%
```

Equals

```
echo %slotOne%  
echo %slotTwo%  
echo %slotThree%
```

And so on...
Is there a way to do that or will i just have to use

```
:Inventory 
cls
echo %slotOne%
echo %slotTwo%
echo %slotThree%
pause<nul
goto ***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is show output via a *two step procedure*: first define an "output format" (represented by your "inventory" variable) comprised of several data variables, and *then* show the values of all previously defined variables via the ECHO of the single format variable. This is possible using *delayed expansion* via this trick: first store the data variables in the "format variable" enclosed in exclamation marks (with delayed expansion disabled), then enable delayed expansion and use a single `echo %inventory%` expansion to show all the values:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^
%empty line 1/2%
%empty line 2/2%

rem Define the "format"
set inventory=!slotOne!!LF!!slotTwo!!LF!!slotThree!

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define a set of values:
set slotOne=Slot one - First set
set slotTwo=Slot two - First set
set slotThree=Slot three - First set

rem Show the first set:
echo First set:
echo %inventory%

rem Define another set of values and show it
set slotOne=Slot one - Second set
set slotTwo=Slot two - Second set
set slotThree=Slot three - Second set
echo/
echo Second set:
echo %inventory%

pause
```

Output:

```
First set:
Slot one - First set
Slot two - First set
Slot three - First set

Second set:
Slot one - Second set
Slot two - Second set
Slot three - Second set
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make an newline variable since batch doesn't have one handy. I've never heard of using ALT+10 like Moncraft suggests, but this way is the closest thing there is to the "standard" way of doing it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set LF=^


:: The above two lines MUST be present or it won't work
set NL=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%

set inventory=%slotOne%%NL%%slotTwo%%NL%%slotThree%
```

Personally, I would suggest using numbers for the slots instead of words (slot[1], slot[2], slot[3], etc.) so that you can just call everything with a `for /L` loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%A in (1,1,3) do echo !slot[%%A]!
```

Comment: Not quite. You either use `!LF!` (in which case `NL` is not needed), or `%NL%`.

Comment: If %NL% translates to a newline character, what does !NL! do?

Comment: To answer my own question, `!NL!` prints a `^` followed by _two_ newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "slotone=Sword"
SET "slottwo=Shield"
SET "slotthree=Rock"

SET "inventory=slotone slottwo slotthree"

ECHO Way the first
FOR %%a IN (%inventory%) DO CALL ECHO(%%%%a%%
ECHO ==========================

ECHO Way the second
FOR %%a IN (%inventory%) DO IF DEFINED %%a CALL ECHO(%%%%a%%
ECHO ==========================

ECHO Way the third
FOR %%a IN (%inventory%) DO FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set %%a') DO ECHO(%%c
ECHO ==========================

ECHO Way the fourth
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set slot') DO ECHO(%%c
ECHO ==========================

SET /a gold=200
SET "header=Your Inventory"
SET "trailer=You have %gold%GP"
ECHO Way the first revisited
FOR %%a IN (header %inventory% trailer) DO CALL ECHO(%%%%a%%
ECHO ==========================
ECHO Way the third revisited
FOR %%a IN (header %inventory% trailer)  DO FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set %%a') DO ECHO(%%c
ECHO ==========================


GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a demo of four different ways and a methodology extension.

The first three ways produce the list in the order defined in `inventory` whereas the fourth relies on variables beginning `slot` and produces the list in alphabetical order of the variables assigned (so `slot01` `slot02` etc would be preferred - it's less typing and intrinsically extensible)